# SpringBoot - read file, path from application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm writing a controller that will download text from a .txt file located in the 'temp' folder and display it on the page.
I did this by a simple method using a Scanner-

```
   @GetMapping("/file")
   @ResponseBody
   public String loadFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
    String test;
    Scanner br = new Scanner(new FileReader("/example/temp/temp.txt"));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (br.hasNext()) {
        sb.append(br.next());
    }
    br.close();
    test = sb.toString();

    return test;
}
```

but the file path should be downloaded from the application.properties file. Anyone got an idea what should I use? I am using SpringBoot 1.5.3.

Comment: You should load it from the classpath using a ClassPathResource: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html

Comment: You mean like an `@Value("${x.y.z.file}")private String filename;` ? In other words, you can use @Value to access the properties that have been set in the application.properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
        @Value("${key that placed in property file}")
        private String file;

        @GetMapping("/file")
        @ResponseBody
        public String loadFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
         String test;
         Scanner br = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));

         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         while (br.hasNext()) {
             sb.append(br.next());
         }
         br.close();
         test = sb.toString();

         return test;
     }
```

Comment: I've already done this just like you before you responded to me;)
And got an exception:

"Could not resolve placeholder 'path.temp.file' in value "${path.temp.file}"

Is adding "path.temp.file = /home/git/example/temp/temp.txt" to "application.properties" correct, or should I do something different?

Answer (score 0):

Best solution:

above answer is good, but to create better code use file instead of String

```
    @Value("${key that placed in property file}")
    private File file;

    @GetMapping("/file")
    @ResponseBody
    public String loadFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
     String test;
     Scanner br = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));

     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     while (br.hasNext()) {
         sb.append(br.next());
     }
     br.close();
     test = sb.toString();

     return test;
 }
```